# How to apply css to ext component

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am creating a component.

Here is my code.

```
{
    xtype : 'component',
    width : 320,
    listeners :{
        afterrender : function(me,eOpts) {
             var divID = this.el.dom.id;
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to customize a my component as a css. there for I am accssing its id.

My question is How to apply css to ext component. By adding the new id and then css with respect to that id or by using the smae id.

Comment: What you have tried yet. Did you checked doc. and know what `cls` do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to access its id. You can define your own id for the component.

```js
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',
  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
      html: 'Hello world!',
      id: 'myComponentId',
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#myComponentId {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check this

Comment: Also one quick question, I wanted this component always on top, for that do I need to give z-index right

Comment: Yes and it should be positioned also